# Genymotion - Fatal Signal 11

Tags: android, android-emulator, genymotion

I've just been trying out the Genymotion emulator and my app always crashes out with the following exception

```
06-03 06:39:22.275: A/libc(1128): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0xb77dd0e0 (code=1), thread 1128
```

My app works fine on actual android phones and even with the Android emulator. This exception is only seen when i try to run it on Genymotion.

I've gone through a few of the answers here and I've tried adding the permissions to the Manifest.I've tried it on multiple images both 4.2.2 and 4.1.1. The same exception can be seen on both the images.

Does anyone know a fix to this ?

Comment: post the full stack trace and relevant code.

Answer (score 1):

Though its late, but this solution helped me-

```
<application        
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/CustomTheme"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:debuggable="true"
        android:vmSafeMode="true"       
        android:allowClearUserData="true"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true" >
```

Add these lines in the manifest file.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you've installed virtual box successfully and deployed the GneyMotion emulators correctly ? If so, try to restart the system again and see if it works. Worst case, I would suggest you to un-install and install it again including virtual box and GenyMotion and Deploy the Gneymotion emulators again. I too faced these issues in my case and re-installation helped me most of the times..

Comment: I'm going to try reinstalling the virtual box and genymotion now. Could it possibly have anything to do with the Arm translation ?

Comment: I don't think anything to do with ARM here as I no where read in entire GneyMotion site mentioning something about any core stuff. Somebody else can pitch in if in case i'm mis-guided here...